# Merge multiple rows into single row then append to csv output file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I have multiple comma-separated files that I need first to merge the rows into a single row then I can append that row to append to one output.csv file.

file-1.txt:

```
CV-1999-0001,
CV-1999-0002,
CV-1999-0003,
CV-1999-0004,
CV-1999-0005,
  ...
```

file-2.txt:

```
CV-2000-0006,
CV-2000-0007,
CV-2000-0008,
....
```

output.csv:

```
IDs
CV-1999-0001,CV-1999-0002,CV-1999-0003,CV-1999-0004,CV-1999-0005
CV-2000-0006,CV-2000-0007,CV-2000-0008,CV-2000-0009,CV-2000-0010
```

I have tried these but none seem to achieve what I need. I still end up with multiple rows

```
echo $(cat /Users/...../"$ROWS".txt) | sed 's/ //g' > "$ROWS_new".txt


echo $(cat paste -s -d "" files-1.txt) | sed 's/ //g' >> output.csv
```

Comment: Where did `CV-2000-0009,CV-2000-0010` come from? Please [edit] your question to make sure that the expected output you provide is **exactly** the output you expect given the same input you provide so it accurately demonstrates your requirements and we have something we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with. And get rid of those `...` lines that are cluttering up your example. Also, if you don't REALLY want `IDs` printed at the top of your output file then don't show it at the top of your output file.

Comment: @EdMorton the files are generated by an external app. I simply access the folders from a shared location and used the data.

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm not asking where your input file comes from, I'm asking where did the strings `CV-2000-0009` and `CV-2000-0010` in your posted expected output come from since they aren't in your posted sample input? Are they from some 3rd input file or do you need this tool to generate them or is it a mistake in your sample input/output? If the former please [edit] your question to explain it, if the latter please [edit] your question to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and reading each file into memory:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -F',\n' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' file-1.txt file-2.txt
CV-1999-0001,CV-1999-0002,CV-1999-0003,CV-1999-0004,CV-1999-0005,
CV-2000-0006,CV-2000-0007,CV-2000-0008,
```

or with GNU awk for multi-char RS and ENDFILE reading 1 line at a time:

```
$ awk -v RS=',\n' -v ORS=',' '1; ENDFILE{printf "\n"}' file-1.txt file-2.txt
CV-1999-0001,CV-1999-0002,CV-1999-0003,CV-1999-0004,CV-1999-0005,
CV-2000-0006,CV-2000-0007,CV-2000-0008,
```

or with any awk reading 1 line at a time:

```
$ awk '
    FNR==1 { printf "%s%s", prev, ors; ors=ORS }
    FNR>1  { printf "%s", prev }
    { prev=$0 }
    END { print prev }
' file-1.txt file-2.txt
CV-1999-0001,CV-1999-0002,CV-1999-0003,CV-1999-0004,CV-1999-0005,
CV-2000-0006,CV-2000-0007,CV-2000-0008,
```

If the last line of your input files end in `,` it'd be easy to remove it but since the sample input in your question ends with `...` we don't know if your input files really end with `,`s or not so I left that as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton the file ends with `,`

Answer (score 0):

Do you try:

```bash
for ROW in ${ROWS}; do
    tr -d "\n" < "/Users/...../${ROW}.txt" \
    | sed -e 's/,$//'
done >> "output.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you @Levallois-Perret  for the response.
 I have tried this but it builds multiple rows for each value in each file and not a row for each files values.

Comment: [Paset bin output](https://pastebin.com/7G79NvMY) this is the output sample.

Answer (score 0):

With a `sed` that offers the `-z` (`--null-data; separate lines by NUL characters`) option, and thus reads the entire input stream, try

```
sed -z 's/\n//g; s/\r/\n/' file1 <(echo $'\r') file2
CV-1999-0001,CV-1999-0002,CV-1999-0003,CV-1999-0004,CV-1999-0005,
CV-2000-0006,CV-2000-0007,CV-2000-0008,
```

Without that option, try

```
sed -f chabo.sed  file1 <(echo $'\r') file2
CV-1999-0001,CV-1999-0002,CV-1999-0003,CV-1999-0004,CV-1999-0005,
CV-2000-0006,CV-2000-0007,CV-2000-0008,
```

with chabo.sed being

```
:L
N
$!bL
s/\n//g
s/^M/\  
/
```

and `^M` the `<cr>` (`0x0D`) character.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this solution?

```
╰─ → $ paste -sd " " file1.txt file2.txt
CV-1999-0001, CV-1999-0002, CV-1999-0003, CV-1999-0004, CV-1999-0005,
CV-2000-0006, CV-2000-0007, CV-2000-0008,
```